# daemon won't register sigint signal

Tags: c, ubuntu, daemon, signals

I'm making a simple daemon that makes a log when the SIGINT and SIGTERM signals are sent, I can already log when a SIGTERM signal is made but when I try to get a SIGINT signal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it seems that the signal isn't made since it isn't saved in the log, also the daemon is running while I try to make a SIGINT signal get sent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define RUNNING_DIR "/tmp"
#define LOCK_FILE   "simple_daemon.lock"
#define LOG_FILE    "simple_daemon.log"

void log_message(filename,message)
char *filename;
char *message;
{
    FILE *logfile;
    logfile=fopen(filename,"a");
    if(!logfile) return;
    fprintf(logfile,"%s\n",message);
    fclose(logfile);
}   

void signal_handler(sig)
int sig;
{
    switch(sig) {

    case SIGTERM:
        log_message(LOG_FILE,"received a SIGTERM signal");
        exit(0);
        break;
    case SIGINT:
        log_message(LOG_FILE, "received a SIGINT signal");
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}

void daemonize()
{
    int i,lfp;
    char str[10];
    if(getppid()==1) return; /* already a daemon */
    i=fork();
    if (i<0) exit(1); /* fork error */
    if (i>0) exit(0); /* parent exits */
    /* child (daemon) continues */
    setsid(); /* obtain a new process group */
    for (i=getdtablesize();i>=0;--i) close(i); /* close all descriptors */
    i=open("/dev/null",O_RDWR); /* open stdin */
    dup(i); /* open stdout */
    dup(i); /* open stderr */
    umask(027); /* set newly created file permissions */
    chdir(RUNNING_DIR); /* change running directory */
    lfp=open(LOCK_FILE,O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0640);
    if (lfp<0) exit(1); /* can not open */
    if (lockf(lfp,F_TLOCK,0)<0) exit(0); /* can not lock */
    /* first instance continues */
    sprintf(str,"%d\n",getpid());
    write(lfp,str,strlen(str)); /* record pid to lockfile */
    signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN); /* ignore child */
    signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_IGN); /* ignore tty signals */
    signal(SIGTTOU,SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTTIN,SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTERM,signal_handler); /* catch kill signal */
    signal(SIGINT,signal_handler); /* catch kill signal */
}

main()
{
    daemonize();
    while(1) sleep(1); /* run */
}
```

I Can't find anything wrong with my code, I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Try `kill -INT <pid>` on the command line.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that it’s not safe to call fopen() (or many other functions) from inside a signal handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send keyboard generated signals to a daemon. You will have to `kill -INT` it.

A terminal can have one foreground process group and several background process groups. Keyboard generated signals get sent to the foreground process group.

A daemon doesn't have a controlling terminal, ergo it can be neither in the foreground nor in the background for any terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Since the daemon by definition is not running in the foreground, it's not the app that'll get SIGINTs when you hit Ctrl+C.  Ctrl+C only affects the foreground app.

Comment: Actually it isn't even running in the background. You see, a terminal can have one foreground process group and several background process groups. A daemon doesn't have a controlling terminal, ergo it can't be neither in the foreground nor in the background for any terminal.

Comment: Good point.  Windows makes me think about "background" differently :)  Edited just a bit.